# azure web app streamlit Uncaught exception GET /_stcore/stream AssertionError

Tags: azure, streamlit

I have an azure web app that runs a streamlit app.

Recently, I have been getting an error:

```
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268534787Z 2023-03-22 12:47:42.267 Uncaught exception GET /_stcore/stream (169.254.129.3)
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268571187Z HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='fvapp.bcpartners.com', method='GET', uri='/_stcore/stream', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='169.254.129.3')
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268577887Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268582587Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 942, in _accept_connection
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268587087Z     open_result = handler.open(*handler.open_args, **handler.open_kwargs)
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268591587Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/streamlit/web/server/browser_websocket_handler.py", line 123, in open
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268596187Z     self._session_id = self._runtime.connect_session(
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268600287Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/streamlit/runtime/runtime.py", line 361, in connect_session
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268604587Z     session_id = self._session_mgr.connect_session(
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268608587Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/streamlit/runtime/websocket_session_manager.py", line 65, in connect_session
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268612887Z     assert (
2023-03-22T12:47:42.268617187Z AssertionError: session with id '7e704886-6f37-4957-a0d9-f87ceef74e11' is already connected!
```

The portion of the code this corresponds to is a button that `generates` some pngs and creates a ppt based on those images, and another button that `downloads` the ppt.

```
with col1:
    result = st.button("Generate")
if result:
    t1 = pd.Timestamp.now()
    st.write(f'Started at {str(pd.Timestamp.now().time())}')
    subprocess.run(["Rscript", "appendix_images_fcn.R", quarter])
    subprocess.run(["Rscript", "pla_fcn.R", quarter])
    
    prs = appendix_fcn.create_appendix(quarter)
    # save the output into binary form
    binary_appendix = BytesIO()
    prs.save(binary_appendix) 
    st.write(f'generated in {str(pd.Timestamp.now()-t1)}')
with col2:
    st.download_button(label = 'Download',
                   data = binary_appendix.getvalue(),
                   file_name = 'Appendix_'+ quarter + '_' + str(pd.Timestamp.now())[2:-7].replace('-','').replace(' ','_').replace(':','') + '.pptx')
```

This error only appears when the download button is selected.

furthermore, it only occurs when a specific quarter is selected.

Does anyone have any ideas to avoid this error, and how it can be dealt with?

Answer (score 0):

> 2023-03-22T12:47:42.268617187Z AssertionError: session with id
> ‘7e704886-6f37-4957-a0d9-f87ceef74e11’ is already connected!

According to the error message, a connection to the session with the ID “7e704886” has already been established. Only when the download button is chosen and only when a certain quarter is chosen this issue occurs. The Streamlit app’s session management appears to be the cause of the problem[session management](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state). Check the code that is generating your images and ppt’s whether it is closing the resources correctly by testing the code locally. Try clearing the session state before generating the PowerPoint as one potential fix like below:-

**Clearing cache:-**

In your command line type:-
`streamlit clear cache` or use this below code:-

```
st.session_state.pop('session_id', None)
```

[image]

Also, You can run these commands to delete items from your session and initializing a new session after that.

```py
# Delete a single key-value pair
del st.session_state[key]

# Delete all the items in Session state
for key in st.session_state.keys():
    del st.session_state[key]
```

I tried creating a sample streamlit app by initializing a session ID and downloading a particular column with name Q1 and it worked successfully like below:-

**Code:-**

```py
import streamlit as st

import pandas as pd

import base64

import io

  

# Initialize session_id attribute

if  "session_id"  not  in st.session_state:

st.session_state["session_id"] = 0

  

# Sample dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({

'Q1': [1, 2, 3],

'Q2': [4, 5, 6],

'Q3': [7, 8, 9]

})

  

# Streamlit app code

def  download_csv():

# Get selected column name

col_name = st.session_state["selected_column"]

if  col_name  is  None:

st.warning("Please select a column to download.")

return

  

# Get selected column data

col_data = df[col_name]

  

# Create dataframe with selected column data

col_df = pd.DataFrame(col_data, columns=[col_name])

  

# Convert dataframe to CSV

csv = col_df.to_csv(index=False)

  

# Convert CSV to bytes

b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode()).decode()

  

# Create download link

href = f'<a href="data:file/csv;base64,{b64}" download="{col_name}.csv">Download {col_name}</a>'

  

# Display download link

st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)

  

# Sidebar with column selection

col_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select column to download", df.columns, key=st.session_state.session_id)

  

# Store selected column name in session state

st.session_state["selected_column"] = col_name

  

# Display sample data for selected column

if  col_name  is  not  None:

col_data = df[col_name]

st.write(f"Sample data for {col_name}:")

st.write(col_data.head())

  

# Download button

if st.button("Download"):

download_csv()

  

# Increment session_id to avoid caching issues

st.session_state.session_id += 1
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can also restart your web app for new session initialization like below:-

[image]

Check the App service Logs to get more insights also run Diagnose and solve problems:-
Check the recommendation for your web app and perform them:-

[image]

Also, the error might occur if there are multiple requests attempting to connect to the same session, Make sure the requests are properly synchronized and also, Try to scale your Web app to more instances.

[image]

**Logs:-**

[image]

***Make sure you follow the session management of your streamlit app from this document below:-***

[Session State - Streamlit Docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state)

Comment: thank you for extensive approach. I will review

Comment: @frank check the updated answer with azure web app